# Blogengine.net have Pages listed in top navagation tabs

Tags: blogengine.net

Is there a way to have static pages list in navigation tabs in Blogengine.net?  So if I create an about page, I can have a tab read 'About' to access that page.  This is something I have done in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your "about" page to be the default home page of the blog then you can:

- Go to Pages and add a new page
- Set the Parent option to `No Parent`
- Check the `Is Front page` checkbox

The will ensure that this page is the home page of your blog.

Alternatively, as blogengine.net is open source you can modify the source code yourself, so if you want to add a new menu item to a page you have created called "about" then you can

- edit the `site.master`
- add a new `li` in the menu section to point to your page e.g `about.aspx`
- You need to ensure that your page that you have created is in the root of your blog.

Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: Well, That is a pain, but I guess it will work.  Of course now I need to diffs whenever I update code.

Answer (score 0):

I modify BlogEngine to have more control over static pages:

http://www.kbdavis07.bloggersonline.com/post/PageLinkMenu.aspx

Its a pending fork to be included into BE in the future.

If you want to use it now you can download the source here:

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/kbdavis07/PageLinkMenu2point0#

The web deployable version is on http://www.kbdavis07.bloggersonline.com/post/PageLinkMenu.aspx